# What is difference in the output of swap -l and swap memory shown in top?

Tags: solaris, swap, top

I am really puzzled to understand the output of `swap -l`, `swap -s` and memory usages reflected by `top` command.

Hence I am not able to finalize that how much SWAP, how much physical memory are used, and how much are free and whether I have to raise memory addition request to sysadmin or not?

Below are the output from my system:

```
$ swap -l
swapfile             dev  swaplo blocks   free
/dev/zvol/dsk/rpool/swap 181,1       8 33554424 **33554424**

$ swap -s
total: 23539804k bytes allocated + 1608016k reserved = **25147820k** used, **10397840k** available


$ prtconf |grep -i Memory
Memory size: 49144 Megabytes
$ top -d 2 -n 2
load averages:  1.36,  1.39,  1.40    19:07:42
120 processes: 118 sleeping, 1 stopped, 1 on cpu

Memory: 48G real, **1411M** free, 24G swap in use, **10G** swap free
```

Below are the uname and memstat details.

Does it mean we should not look into top at all? And report memory usages in the basis of memstat only?

why swap -l and swap -s are not havign similar stat?

```
bash-3.2$ uname -a
SunOS l28sdp1a 5.10 Generic_150401-03 i86pc i386 i86pc

 =================Memstat======================
Page Summary                Pages                MB  %Tot
------------     ----------------  ----------------  ----
Kernel                    1602713              6260   13%
ZFS File Data             4345496             16974   35%
Anon                      4974599             19432   40%
Exec and libs               32588               127    0%
Page cache                 948627              3705    8%
Free (cachelist)              972                 3    0%
Free (freelist)            673589              2631    5%

Total                    12578584             49135
Physical                 12250367             47852
```

Please help me to undestand.

Comment: Blocks != (kilo)bytes.  And for the human-readable tallies (e. g. `1411M`), it depends on whether the author of the tool is dividing Kilobytes by 1,000 or 1,024.  Is one megabyte 1,024 bytes * 1,024; or 1,024 bytes * 1,000; or just 1,000,000 bytes?  Is a Gigabyte 1,024 bytes * ( 1,024 * 1,024 ); or 1,024b * (1,024 * 1,000); or 1024b * (1,000 * 1,000); or just 1,000,000,000 bytes?

Answer (score 1):

As the tag is Solaris I assume you are running Solaris.
As a ex-Solaris admin, I really do not like to have top installed as it is misleading when reporting swap usage vs memory usage. Solaris uses the concept of virtual memory that mixes swap and memory. Although you have a swap device, swap might be allocated in memory if there is plenty available. If you trully want to find out exactly how much swap your system is using it will be a time-consuming job. This is possible by using pmap -x on each process and check the swap part.

If you are running a single application on the system then your sys admin should be able to execute echo "::memstat"|mdb -l. This will provide the current memory status and I expect they should have some monitoring in place checks the memory.

Ifyou applicaton is not the only inthe server and it is running under a specific user id you can do ps -u  to provide how much it is consuming.

Hoep this helps

Comment: SunOS l28sdp1a 5.10 Generic_150401-03 i86pc i386 i86pc